# SQL query is not working properly(numbers)

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am developing php script with MySQL . I stored genre datas as "1, 2 ,3"(IDs)

Then I have a problem with searching data.

My Data table is:

metas table

```
-------------------
meta_id,meta_genres
--------------------
|1     |1,2,3      |

|2     |10,3,4     |

|3     |12,3,5     |

-------------------
```

my query is

```
SELECT * FROM metas WHERE meta_genres LIKE '%1%'
```

then return ids: 1,2,3

I want to it returns just 1.

How can I fix it ?

Best Regards.

Comment: @Gowri : nope...this would fail if 1 is in last..like 4,3,1!

Comment: You question isn't that precise, so I'll assume that you want to get the ID (tell me if I guess wrong) of the meta_genre which fit your need. So you should just change the SQL query in `SELECT meta_id FROM metas WHERE meta_genre LIKE '%1%';`

Comment: If you can't normalize your tables properly, use [FIND_IN_SET()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) but you should really normalize for better efficiency

Comment: I would advise you to bring your database up to the 3rd normalize form! ->http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization

Comment: `SELECT * FROM metas WHERE meta_genres LIKE '%1,% OR meta_genres like '%,1%` should do the trick

Comment: Dear Gowri it doesn't work if meta_genres: 3,4,1

Comment: Using LIKE is __never__ the best answer to this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use REGEXP to find only separated `1` in set input

```
SELECT * FROM metas WHERE meta_genres REGEXP '[[:<:]]1[[:>:]]'
```

Answer (score 4):

Use [FIND_IN_SET(str,strlist) function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set):

```
SELECT *
 FROM metas
 WHERE FIND_IN_SET(1, meta_genres)
```

**EDIT:** if there are spaces before commas (e.g. `1 , 2 , 3`) in meta_genres then above query can return empty set. To work around:

```
SELECT *
 FROM metas
 WHERE FIND_IN_SET(1, REPLACE(meta_genres, ' ', ''));
```

Comment: Dear Rimas, Your answer seems to be good. However it returns nothing. My query is true but I don't understand

Answer (score -1):

You Will never retrive just 1, thats because the numbers after 1 is part of 2,3 string. So the query does not look at these numbers as individual numbers but simply as a whole string.....