# MySQL Select: Find if a single value exists in an array field

Tags: php, mysql

I've a field "locations" containing values in format 1,4,7,8 etc.

I want to exclude rows that contain a specific value. eg: `$location = 4;`

I tried: `SELECT * FROM users WHERE FIND_IN_SET($location, locations) = 0`

Also tried some combinations with IN .. !IN but again no results. Any suggestion?

Thank you

Comment: `SELECT * FROM users WHERE location<>'$location'` ? You want to exclude data based from a submitted form, right?

Comment: uhmm, it's working on fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1dab9/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed by John Woo your query must work. If not then may be data in the `locations` contains values with spaces before commas, for example: `1,4 ,7,8`. In this case [`FIND_IN_SET` isn't working as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26213489/3908097). So you can try:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE NOT(locations REGEXP '[[:<:]]$location[[:>:]]')
```

[`[[:<:]], [[:>:]]` stand for word boundaries](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/regexp.html#operator_regexp), so `[[:<:]]4[[:>:]]` will match `4` in list, but not `14`.

Test and see difference on [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8ee24/1)

Comment: 1.- Confirmed that there is no space between locations. 2.- Your example bring parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING)

Comment: I replace the variable $location with the actual value and it works, but works on the opposite way. Maybe if I remove NOT?

Comment: Did you enclose this query with double quotes `"` in php script?

Comment: This is my query right now: "SELECT * FROM users WHERE NOT(locations REGEXP '[[:<:]]".$location."[[:>:]]') AND active=1 AND hidden=0" As I wrote before works, but opposite way. In cases that normal should not shows rows, it shows them, and in cases that it must shows data, it does not shows.

Comment: Ok. I removed NOT from query and now works as expecetd. Maybe I was not clear by saying that "EXCLUDE".

Answer (score 0):

SELECT * FROM users WHERE FIND_IN_SET($location, locations) != 0

Comment: I would think it should be $location='4' as FIND_IN_SET is a string function. Hard to tell without seeing the field types.    http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set refers.

Comment: Field locations is a VARCHAR field type, so it's ok. I had a typo before. I want to EXCLUDE rows. I tried your suggestion but unfortunately does not works. Also tried !FIND_IN_SET($location, locations) > 0 . Nothing. What must be first parameter? The variable or the field name?

Comment: Take a look at John Woo's answer above. Follow the link to his jfiddle. It is working, so that should help you?, so try "SELECT * FROM users WHERE FIND_IN_SET('$location', locations) = 0"